# Finding a parabola with vertex $(b, a)$ if the vertex of the parabola $y=3x^2-12x+9$ is $(a,b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If the vertex of the parabola

$y=3x^2-12x+9$ is $(a,b)$

Then the parabola(s) whose vertex is $(b,a)$ is (are)

A) $y=x^2+6x+11$

B) $y=x^2-7x+3$

C) $y=-2x^2-12x-16$

D) $y=-2x^2+16x-13$

This is a multiple choice based question. I tried, but I am not able to get it. Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome! I advise to always show your attempt to any question.
Now, my hint is to simply find $(a,b)$ and then compare those with the results computable from the other four quadratic functions.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Actually i tried that method but I am only able to get the c option not the a option. I am not able to find out where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: Sorry for the english.

Comment: Both options (a) and (c) are correct.  Again, please edit your question to show your attempt so we can see what errors you made, if any.

Comment: Have you even found $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes I found a and b but all the time I did mistake in founding vertex of a option each and every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your function as : $y=3(x^2-4x+3)=3(x-3)(x-1)$. The axis of symmetry (x coordinate of vertex) is $\frac{3+1}{2}=2$.Then plug in to find $y$ value of vertex which is $-3$.

So $(a,b)=(2,-3)$

Now find vertex of all your options (axis of symmetry can be calculated by $\frac{-b}{2a}$):

A)

$\frac{-6}{2}$ which is $-3$ So check $y$ value and see that it is $2$ which is $(b,a)$ as desired.

B)

$\frac{7}{2}$ not right either

C)

$\frac{-12}{4}=-3$ Plug in to find $y$ value of vertex and see that it is $2$.

D)

$\frac{16}{4}$ not right either

So A and C are the correct answers

Comment: Thanks now I got what mistake i was doing.